# div that changes another divs background image on hover without being a parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to find a solution that works anytime within any kind of browser ( to reach wider audience ), and I want a list, which ones each li element changes the background of a specific div.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihL2R.jpg this is the desired look of it.

My code looks like this:

HTML:

```
    <div id="container">

        <div id="div1">

            <ul>

                <li>item1<li>
                <li>item2<li>
                <li>item3<li>
                <li>item4<li>
                <li>item5<li>
                <li>item6<li>

            </ul>         

        </div>

        <div id="div2>

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}

#div2 {
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 422px;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

#container {
    min-width: 768px;
    max-width: 991px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The divs are already next to each other, of there is an error please pass on, doesn't matter, I just rewrote it from heart ( I don't have it in front of me ).

I want the list item to change the background image of the right floating div. The list is NOT the parent element of the div, so I could not find any way, sadly I'm not good enough from jquery to solve this yet. Thank you for your answers in advance, I hope someone can help me! :)

Sorry if it is a duplicate, could not find a reasonable answer yet.

EDIT:

Here is a better view of it:

http://kepfeltoltes.hu/160731/idea_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

Comment: Not possible with CSS alone. You have the jQuery tag - have you tried something already?

Comment: It is possible to achieve the same visual effect with pure CSS, but slightly different HTML. But yeah, if you need to keep this structure, then you will have to use javascript

Comment: Since sometimes browsers give up loading java I guess it would not work sometimes, I tried a few jqueries I found on stackoverflow, but none of them worked in this structure, and yes, I have to keep this structure.

Comment: pure CSS example (different HTML) - https://jsfiddle.net/ehkko2sa/

Comment: A question that was already asked pretty often. With pure css is it not possible. That's why it's called 'cascading style Sheets'. It would be possible if you change the html layout.

Comment: As I said I don't want it to be pure, it would be preferably only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jQuery:

```
// define event handlers hover for li
$('ul').on('mouseover', 'li:eq(0)', {bg:'background_url_1'}, onHover);
$('ul').on('mouseover', 'li:eq(1)', {bg:'background_url_2'}, onHover);
$('ul').on('mouseover', 'li:eq(2)', {bg:'background_url_3'}, onHover);
..

function onHover(e)
{
   $('#div2').css({background: 'url(' + e.data.bg + ')'});
}
```

Comment: Sadly I'm not really familiar with jquery yet, can you explain how should it work?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript library. It is best to read here - jquery.com